# Can two radio tags be used to set boolean values for a form property in struts?

Tags: html, struts-1, struts-html

I'm new-ish to struts and I'm particularly stuck on an area of struts code which has to do with the radio button. No matter what I do I can't get anything but a false value from the following: (CostForm)

```
<td align="left" width="200px" colspan="2">
    <html:radio property="responsableBool" value="false"/>No
    <html:radio property="responsableBool" value="true"/>Yes
</td>
```

It is then initialised from this piece of code:

```
CostForm costform = (CostForm) form;
Cost cost = new Cost();
costform.populateModel(cost);
```

and the populateModel just has: `PropertyUtils.copyProperties(cost,this);`

The only thing I can think of is that struts doesn't allow the radio buttons to reference the same property with different values.

Comment: Not allowing radio buttons to reference the same property with different values would kind of eliminate what radio buttons are *for*.

Comment: Well I thought so too except for some reason I can't only get one value from the form no matter what option I choose. SoI'd just like to clarify that it can be done.

Comment: Might need to see more, or detail the submission process--it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the form:

```
public class CostForm extends ActionForm {
    private boolean responsableBool; // And getter/setter
}
```

The HTML:

```
<html:form action="/costsub">
    <html:radio property="responsableBool" value="false"/>No
    <html:radio property="responsableBool" value="true"/>Yes
    <html:submit/>
</html:form>
```

The action:

```
public ActionForward execute([args elided]) throws Exception {
    CostForm costForm = (CostForm) form;
    System.out.println(costForm.isResponsableBool());
    // etc.
```

When I click "No" and "Yes" I get the expected boolean value inside the action.

I'd double-check things like spelling (the English spelling would be "responsible"; perhaps it's spelled correctly in `Cost`?), action/form mismatches (are you using the right form "name" in the action mapping?), and so on.

Comment: @DarkStar1 The most fun kind of debugging ;)

Comment: @DarkStar1 It was sarcasm, but you're working with Struts 1, so... probably horrible ;)

Comment: Just a quick question; does it have to be declared in the form bean as a property?

Comment: @DarkStar1 If you want to access it via the form, yep.

Comment: No matter what I do it still evaluates to false.

Comment: @DarkStar1 Create a minimally failing, complete example on github, I'll take a look. You don't have to include all the libraries, but put a readme with a list of what you're deploying and the versions. So should include an example action or two, a form with the boolean, a jsp, any custom struts functionality, and the config.

Comment: I wish this cold be easily done. It's a huge software that I have to maintain pending redevelopment, with this one crucial bug to fix. I'm in the freenode irc struts channel until I can figure this out. Thanks for pointing me to github. Never heard of it before.

Comment: @DarkStar1 It's easily done; I created an S1 project with a form, actions, and configs to make sure I hadn't totally forgotten how it all worked in maybe 10 minutes, from scratch. You can do the same, adding the stuff that's different in your app, until it breaks. Bottom line is there's *some* assumption you're making about flow, types, property/property names, etc. that's likely incorrect.

Comment: I am trying to build a minimal version atm. But I should mention that every other property value entered in the form is persisted in the database so tbh I'm not sure the struts flow could be at fault, could be that the java class is somehow interfering but I have checked that to death.

Comment: Many things can affect the flow, it's not just "did I hit the form and get the right form back", there might be a custom request processor snarfing properties, etc.